# l[:] performance problem

Tags: python, django

Recently I was debugging a code like following

```
def getList():
    #query db and return a list
    total_list = Model.objects.all()
    result = list()
    for item in total_list:
        if item.attr1:
            result.append(item)
    return result


# in main code    
org_list = getList()
list = orgList[:]#this line cause cpu problems.

if len(org_list)>0 and org_list[0].is_special:
    my_item = org_list[0]

for i in list:
    print_item(i)

doSomethingelse(list[0])
```

In order to simplify the code I change most of it but the main part is here.

In getList method we query db and get 20~30 rows. Then we create a python list from it and return it.
in main method we get org_list variable from getList method
and slice it with orgList[:]

and loop over this list and call spesific elements on it like list[0]

The problem here is that this code runs on a really busy server and unfortunaletty it uses most of the cpu and eventually locks our servers.
Problem here is the line that we slice list varibale with list[:]
if we dont do that and just use org_list variable instead our servers does not have a problem. Does anybosy have any idea why that might happen. is slicing uses alot of cpu or when we use a sliced list. does it uses alot of cpu?

Comment: can you not perform the same functionality on the model without turning it into a list? django model returns an itterable object - Therefore you can still perform `len(Model.objects.all())` and or `Model.objects.all()[0]` without `list = orglist[:]`. Although CPU usage will depend on how many objects are returned.

Comment: Slicing such a tiny list should never cause a noticable performance hit. Could you show us the real code instead?

Comment: getList method does alot of calculating and after that calculations it decides which object to put in a list.but other that that you are absolutely right. it is always better to not to convert your querysets into a list.

Comment: when we remove the slicing code. performance issue just disapeared. I found out that when you slice a list. it actually works as a view to that list and just call original list methods to get actual item.

Comment: @yilmazhuseyin: That is absolutely wrong in pure Python. A slice creates a new list in pure Python. In NumPy, slicing an array creates a view to the array so maybe that's where this came from somehow.

Comment: @Justin Peel I found out that when we slice an iterable. we actually send a slice object to __getitem__ method of this object and this method returns the result. so in my case I misjudged the result I got. It seems like list object's __getitem__ method is returning another list object which has no connection with the first list.

Answer (score 2):

The code that you are showing would run in the 0.1 microseconds that it would take to raise an exception:

```
org_list = getList()
list = orgList[:]#this line cause cpu problems.
```

`orgList` should be `org_list`. Show the minimal code that actually reproduces the problem.

Also, that kills the `list` built-in function. Don't do that.

**Update** Another thought: A common response to "My Django app runs slowly!" is "turn off the debug flag" ... evidently it doesn't free up memory in debug mode.

**Update2** about """I found out that when you slice a list. it actually works as a view to that list and just call original list methods to get actual item.""" Where did you get that idea? That can't be the case with a plain old list! Have you redefined `list` somewhere?

In your `getList` function:

(1) put in `print type(list)`

(2) replace `result = list()` with `result = []` and see whether the problem goes away.

Comment: I created a queryset objects which is an iterable and you can call spesific elements on it like so ,myQuerySet[5]. when I do a list(myQuerySet), it calls all the elements on query set and creates a list. but when I do a qs2 = MyQuerySet[:] then qs2 does not query anything but qs2[4] actually calls myQuerySet[4] and returns the result.

Comment: is there any difference between list() and [] . I thought they are identicle

Comment: type(list) returns <type 'list'>

Comment: @yilmazhuseyin type(list) beeing <type 'list'> : is it really in getList() as John Machin asked for ??! In getList, list isn't re-assigned to another object, so it is the build-in object list everywhere in the getList function. With my Python 2.7, print type(list) gives me : <type 'type'>

Comment: @eyquem Sorry that was my bad. in getList functin type(list) returned <type 'type'>

Answer (score 0):

`list = org_list[:]` makes a copy of `org_list`.  Usually you see something like this when you need to modify the list but you want to keep the original around as well.

The code you are showing me doesn't seem like it actually modifies org_list, and if `doSomethingelse(list[0])` doesn't modify list, I don't see why it's actually being copied in the first place.  Even if it does modify `list`, as long as `org_list` isn't needed after those few lines of code, you could probably get away with just using `org_list` and not doing the slice copy.

Comment: That was exactly what we did and solve the problem. But I don't really understand why slicing causes such problems. It locked our servers some how.

Comment: So not doing the slice gets rid of the performance problem?  That seems odd for such small lists.

Comment: Yes this is the weird thing. We remove that line and everything went to its normal state. But our server probably receives 100's of requests at a time. so this code runs like a hundred time at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to know:

- what is the type of **total_list** ? Please do **print type(total_list)**
- what are the types of the elements of **total_list** ?
- have you an idea of the sizes of these elements ?
- what is the number of elements in the list returned by **getList()** ? 20-30 ?

Remarks:

-giving the keyword "list" as a name for a list isn't a good idea (in **list = orgList[:]** )

-your **getList** function can be written :

```
def getList():
    #query db and return a list
    total_list = Model.objects.all()
    return [ item for item in total_list if item.attr1 ]
```

Comment: If we're going to rewrite this code anyway: `return Model.objects.filter(attr1 = True)`

Comment: type of total list is <type 'list'> , and the problem is not with the element sizes there is only 20-30 of them and they are regular django Model objects.

Comment: @yilmazhuseyin Since total_list is a list object, your getList() function can be written def getList(): return [ item for item in Model.objects.all() if item.attr1 ] and a dedicated function getList for this creation isn't absolutely required. Appealing a function is time-costing. It won't solve your problem, though.

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately actual code is property of the company I worked for so I cannot give it exactly like it is but here is some part of it (variable names are changed,but argument of mainTree method was really named list.)

```
    mainObj = get_object_or_404(MainObj, code_name=my_code_name)
    if (not mainObj.is_now()) and (not request.user.is_staff):
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/")

    main_tree = mainObj.main_tree()
    objects = main_tree[:] # !!!
    if objects.__len__() == 1 and not objects[0].has_special_page:
        my_code_name = objects[0].code_name

...
...
...

mainObj.main_tree() is the following

    def main_tree(self):
        def append_obj_recursive(list, obj):
            list.append(obj)
            for c in self.obj_set.filter(parent_obj=obj):
                append_obj_recursive(list, c)
            return list

        root_obj = self.get_or_create_root_obj();
        top_level_objs = self.obj_set.filter(parent_obj=root_obj).order_by("weight")
        objs = []

        for tlc in top_level_objs:
            append_obj_recursive(objs, tlc)
        return objs
```

This is a really weird problem. slicing  should not cause such a bizare problem. If I can find an answer I will post it here too.